# Select / Unselect user control

Tags: c#, user-controls, multipleselection

I am creating an application in which i have a user control that can be added by user dynamically any number of times. Form also contains some other controls.

Suppose he has added the control 10 times.

**Requirement:**

> 1) When the control is selected, it should be highlighted and when the
>   other control is selected then the previous control looses the glow.
>
> 2) User can select multiple controls at the same time. Now all the
>   selected controls should be highlighted and the selection has to be
>   made with ctrl key.

There is also a possibility of moving the controls on the form.

**What I have achieved:**

> 1) I am able to add multiple controls dynamically.
>
> 2) I can change the location of one control dynamically.
>
> 3) I am able to highlight the control when it is clicked, but not able
>   to un-glow it when user has clicked elsewhere. Need to know which event of User control can be used for that. -- Got the solution for this. On mouse click i made the focus on the control and then handle GotFocus and Lost Focus events to golw and un-glow the control.

**Problem Left:**

> No success in **selecting multiple controls** and dragging them
>   simultaneously. If i would be able to select multiple controls then
>   dragging would not be very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about buttons, unfortunately you cant select multiple at a time..

Comment: I am talking about User Control.

Comment: I think then you can have a look at here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314410/drag-multiple-selected-controls

Comment: the link does not explain how to select multiple controls simultaneously. It explains how to move the control.